# Difference between lattice and wiener FIR filter

Tags: filters, dsp-core, wiener-filter

I know the structure of lattice and wiener filter. But I though FIR filter is always FIR (wiener, tap + delay) filter, But what is the advantage of lattice structure, which in the CMSIS DSP filter algorithms we have two FIR filter, one for wiener and another for lattice!
As you can see here in [two](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/group__groupFilters.html) name:

```
Finite Impulse Response (FIR) Filters (arm_fir_lattice_f32)

Finite Impulse Response (FIR) Lattice Filters (arm_fir_f32)
```

Also I can't relate lattice filter with reallity, wiener is easlly realated since its coefficients are the impulse response of system. But what about lattice?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by FIR filter is always FIR filter? There are many design methods for FIR filters, each comes with it advantages and disadvantages. Do you want to know them for both types ?

Comment: In essence I'm asking what is the advantage of lattice FIR structure in DSP processor and why (philosophy)?@Irreducible.

Comment: @PeterK. why deleted your answer? Thq quote yo've attached was most of the answer. Maybe sometime I need to look at that, if you could at least, comment that. But if you could undelete I will accept that. Maybe there is no magical answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heared lattice filters for IIR all pole filters are exactly coefficients of linear constant coefficient differential equations LCCDE. Then if coefficients of lattice filter all became smaller that 1, we are aware that our filter is stable.

[image: lattice advantaga]